# When i make use of the getRandomNumber(); it gets a random number on page reload but does not change the random number on button click

Tags: javascript

OnClick of my submit button, the random function is supposed to refresh but mine remains the same. So i tried a different approach and it worked. To get the desired result i wrote my code inside the a playGame function Like this.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("number-submit").addEventListener("click", playGame);
    document.getElementById("restart-game").addEventListener("click", initGame);

}

function playGame() {
    let numberGuess = document.getElementById("number-guess").value;
    console.log(numberGuess);

    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
    console.log(randomNumber);

    if (numberGuess > randomNumber) {
        console.log("Too High, Try Again");
    } else if (numberGuess < randomNumber) {
        console.log("Too Low, Try Again");
    } else {
        console.log("Congratulations This Is Correct!!");
    }
}
```

i tried writhing a getRandomNumner() function after trying out my solution to see if i could make my code better but using the code provided below does not provide the desired result for me.
When i make use of the getRandomNumber(); it gets a random number on page reload but does not change the random number on click of the button.
What are my doing wrong??
This is my getRandomNumber function.

```
let correctNumber = getRandomNumber();
console.log(correctNumber);

function getRandomNumber(){

let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    return randomNumber;
}
```

WHAT ARE MY DOING WRONG WITH THE getRandomNumber() ??

Comment: Where is the code that tells the computer to change the random number on click of the button?

Comment: Please show the full code in the second example too. It's not clear, what did you change other than the part you included.